# Determining $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$when $f(x)=\frac1{2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I just need help figuring out where I’m going wrong on this one.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tDqU.jpg]

Comment: If $f(x)=ax+b$, then what is $f(x+3)$ and $f(x) + 3$?

Answer (score 4):

$f(x+h)=\frac  1{2(x+h)}$. (You have to replace $x$ by $x+h$).

Comment: So I only substitute 1/2x in for f(x) and not the f(x+h)? I was given that problem and have to find where they made their mistake. If you put 1/2x in for all the x’s I feel like it’s correct?

Comment: @Phil To find $f(x+h)$ when $f(x)$ is given you have to just change $x$ to $x+h$ wherever you find it the definition of $f(x)$.

Comment: @Phil I think you are mistaking $f(x+h)$ for $f(x)+h$.

Comment: Yeah I think that is where I’m confused. So what would the simplified expression be with everything substituted in correctly?

Comment: You should get  $-\frac 1 {2x(x+h)}$